# Solr data indexing , returns only one field

Tags: mysql, indexing, solr, dataimporthandler

I am trying to use solr for indexing data from my data base. 
After I index data, when I query *.* 
I get just the id field in result. not all the fields which I had in my query.

My data-config.xml

```
<document name="content">
    <entity name="documen" query="SELECT indexId ,brand_id, category_id, product_name from Production">
        <field column="indexId" name="id" /> 
        <field column="category_id" name="categoryid" />
        <field column="brand_id" name="brandid" />
        <field column="product_name" name="id" />
    </entity>
</document>
```

My schema.xml looks like this :

```
<field name="id" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
<field name="categoryid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/> 
<field name="brandid" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="productname" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

When I query using `*.*` I get

```
<doc>
<str name="id">1</str>
<long name="_version_">1426653005792411648</long></doc>
<doc>
<str name="id">2</str>
<long name="_version_">1426653005793460224</long></doc>
<doc>
```

I get only "id" field as result.

Actually, whatever field is in "uniquekey" tag is returned as query result

Comment: why is product_name field mapped to id ? can you run the DIH in debug through UI and check if the values are getting picked.

Comment: I got all the four fields in my query result..

I had not put my field in schema.xml in "fields" tag. for querying my indexed database "defaultsearchfield" field still DOES not works. I have to specify which field to search in.